# Regular expression timeout

Tags: javascript, regex

i trying to extract if blocks of code from some code using regular expression, but when missing curly brackets in code my browser blocked from infinity loop.
This is my regular expression and  example of code without curly bracket

```
if\s*([A-z0-9]+)?\s*\((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)\s*\{(?:[^}{]+|\{(?:[^}{]+|\{[^}{]*\})*\})*\}
```

Example:

```
if(true){
    if(true){

    }


if(true){
}
```

How to prevent browser from timeout in this case if possible.

Comment: what 's the reason for `([A-z0-9]+)?\s*` between `if` and the first `(`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the input you are processing is extremely "regular", regular expressions won't help you here. You can't express the fact that parantheses must be matched, for example in a simple regular expression.

If the code you're parsing is simple enough, you could roll your own parser, aware of only the structure it needs in order to do the extraction you want. You haven't mentioned what language you're trying to parse, but from the "javascript" tag I'll take it to be javascript. It might work for it better than for C/C++ etc. Otherwise, you need to look at some already available parses, which will produce an AST or similar, and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a bit indirectly, you could make a first pass simply to check bracket counts.  However, brackets within comments or strings will likely mess that up, and that's true for syntactically valid input as well as your example.  (My first instinct is that this feels a bit like the "never use regex to parse HTML" conversation, but I could be wrong.)